# Woocommerce | Clear cart by Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to set up an AJAX function to clear my cart

**HTML**

```
<a onclick="clearCart(this)" data-href="/product-page/" data-productID="182">Go to Product</a>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function clearCart(d) {
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        var productID = d.getAttribute("data-productID");
        $.ajax({
            url: "addtocart.php",
            data: {productID: productID},
            type: "post",
            success: function(output) {
                window.location = d.getAttribute("data-href");
                //alert(output);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

**PHP**

```
if(isset($_POST['productID']) && !empty($_POST['productID'])) {   
    global $woocommerce;
    $woocommerce->cart->empty_cart();
    //echo $_POST['productID'];
}
```

**Result**

- Internal Server Error caused by 3rd PHP line
- Alerting var output is working (check outcommented code)

**SOLUTION**

I figured it out by myself and some great help from @MirzaP

JS

```
      function clearCart(d) {
            jQuery.post(
                "https://dercampus.ch/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php", 
                //ajaxurl, 
                {
                    "action": "clearcart",
                    "data":   d.getAttribute("data-productid")
                }, 
                function(){
                    window.location = d.getAttribute("data-href");
                }
            );
        }
```

PHP

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_clearcart',function(){
    global $woocommerce;
    $woocommerce->cart->empty_cart();
});
```

Comment: When you set WP_DEBUG to true in your wp-config.php what is the internal error that gets shown?

Comment: It doesn't show anything for this php file. Do I need to adjust anything as it is an AJAX call?
The file is located in a subdirectory in my plugin

Comment: Does it show anything in the browser console when you do right click -> Inspect Element -> Console (in chrome)?

Comment: This is shown on click

http://dercampus.ch/log.png

Comment: When you set WP_DEBUG to true and then do the same is the error 500 expanded on? Or if with the flag set to true if you click on the addtocart.php url itself does anything happen?
Also, you should really be using the admin-ajax.php file for ajax calls with WordPress.

Comment: I don't think so, feel free to check it out https://dercampus.ch/en/

I'll be reading about admin-ajax.php in the meanwhile

Answer (score 2):

Please change your php code to

```
if(isset($_POST['data']) && !empty($_POST['data'])) {   
    global $woocommerce;
    $woocommerce->cart->empty_cart();
    //echo $_POST['productID'];
}
```

Your parameter that is passed in is data and not productID

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, I've modified the post to make it better readable and forgot to adjust the AJAX call. Please check out the edited post.

Comment: You should try doing some echo statements inside your php call https://dercampus.ch/wp-content/plugins/dercampus/assets/php/addtocart.php?productId=test to make sure when access directly things are getting somewhere... change _POST in the php code to _REQUEST... of course, in the end product you would remove the echos and also pass in an nonce to prevent direct access etc.

Comment: I figured it out in the meanwhile, check the updated post. Thanks a lot for your time and the the ajax-admin and WP_DEBUG hint!

Comment: Great to hear you have figured it out!

Comment: Also, go ahead and change `global $woocommerce` to `WC()`. The global has been long deprecated in favor of the function that returns the instance of the main WooCommerce class.

Answer (score 0):

```html
// before addto cart, only allow 1 item in a cart
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'woo_custom_add_to_cart_before' );
 
function woo_custom_add_to_cart_before( $cart_item_data ) {
 
    global $woocommerce;
    $woocommerce->cart->empty_cart();
 
    // Do nothing with the data and return
    return true;
}
```