# Clear WooCommerce cart on Currency Switcher change

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using the currency switcher WordPress plugin to change currencies on my website, I want the cart to be cleared once I change the currency. I've been trying for some time now, but can't figure out why it isn't working.

This is my source code in the theme functions.php file

```
    function currency_change_action_callback() {      
    global $woocommerce;
    $url_data=$_POST['url_data'];
     $woocommerce->cart->empty_cart();   
        echo $url_data;
        
    
    die();   
    }
add_action( 'wp_ajax_currency_change_action', 'currency_change_action_callback' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_currency_change_action', 'currency_change_action_callback' );
```

I've also tried creating a javascript file and calling it to my functions.php file. here are my source codes

**app.js**

```
    $('#alg_currency_select').on('change', function () {
    function Clearcart(d){
            jQuery.post(
                "http://localhost/epay/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php", 
                //ajaxurl, 
                {
                    "action": "clearcart",
                    "data":   d.getAttribute("data-product")
                }, 
                function(){
                    window.location = d.getAttribute("data-href");
                }
            );
       
})};
```

**functions.php**

```
    function load_javascript() {
    wp_register_script('custom', get_template_directory_uri().'/app.js', 'jquery', 1, true);
    wp_enqueue_script('custom');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_javascript');
```

would greatly appreciate it if someone can help me solve the issue of why my cart isn't clearing. thanks.

Comment: What is `echo $url_data;` supposed to achieve?

Comment: `.on('change', function () { function Clearcart(d){` makes no sense. No one is calling that function `Clearcart` anywhere.

Comment: @CBroe i've removed the echo statement. however i am unsure on the ClearCart function. I refered to another link "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40174894/woocommerce-clear-cart-by-ajax" and just used that code in hopes that it would clear my cart. what changes would you recommend i make?

Comment: Well execute the code inside the event handler callback, instead of wrapping it into _another_ function? Unclear though what `d` is supposed to be here. Resp. what sense passing any additional parameter would make in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some mistakes in your code and unnecessary things.

In the code below, the jQuery code is now located in a php function and enqueued in WordPress using the WooCommerce `wc_enqueue_js()` function.

```
// The jQuery Ajax enqueued code
add_action('template_redirect', 'currency_change_trigger_clear_cart_js' );
function currency_change_trigger_clear_cart_js() {
    wc_enqueue_js( "jQuery( function($){
        $(document.body).on('change', '#alg_currency_select', function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: '" . admin_url('/admin-ajax.php') . "',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    'action': 'currency_change_clear_cart'
                },
                success: function(response) {
                    if( response == 'cleared' ) {
                        $(document.body).trigger('wc_fragment_refresh'); // Refresh cart
                    }
                    // console.log(response);
                }
            });
        });
    });" );
}

// Php AJAX receiver: Empty cart
add_action( 'wp_ajax_currency_change_clear_cart', 'currency_change_clear_cart' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_currency_change_clear_cart', 'currency_change_clear_cart' );
function currency_change_clear_cart() { 
    if( count(WC()->cart->get_cart()) > 0 ) {
        WC()->cart->empty_cart();   
        echo 'cleared';
    }
    die();   
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: the code works perfectly. thank you so much. i still have to understand how it works but i won't stop till i do.